# Angular 2 template reference variable with *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have two components: list and detail

In **list component** I want to render multiple **detail components**.

**list.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'detail',
    templateUrl: './detail.component.html'
})
export class DetailComponent {
    @ViewChild('details') details;

    public items = {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**list.component.html**

```
<detail *ngFor="let item of items" #details></detail>
```

Notice the **#details** tempalte reference variable. I want to access all of the detail components. It is possible to make the **#details** variable an array ?

Answer (score 7):

```
@ViewChildren('details') details:QueryList<DetailComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.details.toArray());
  this.details.changes.subscribe(changes => {
    console.log(this.details.toArray());
  });
}
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: Basically if it is nested with ng-content we can switch to @ContentChildren correct?

Comment: @Winnemucca yes